# Why does OnDrawItem event for a ListView not affect the Design-time environment?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, windows-forms-designer, design-time

If I create a class and make it derive from a ListView like this...

```
class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView() : base()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        OwnerDraw = true;
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        Scrollable = false;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnDrawItem(e);
    }
}
```

Then I open the design view of my windows form and add a new MyListView object then add a single item and link it to a image list.  I can see that there is one item in the mylistview object.  It has no effect on the object I have on my form called `lv` of type `MyListView`.  When I run my app on the other hand I see exactly what I expected and there is no items listed.

Why would this effect run-time and not design-time painting?

[image]

Comment: Umm...  OK well I paste that code into a new class file, then open my form and click on the toolbox and drag it onto the form.  I select the new object on the form and change `LargeImageList` to my imagelist and edit items to include one item with an image from the imagelist and it's using the default `View` of `LargeIcon`.  It shows the item just fine at design-time but run it and there is nothing displayed...  How you are getting it to work is amazing to me.

Comment: Not setting the View property is a pretty big mistake, matters a lot when you custom-draw.  Right now you are just seeing it draw the label, that's not custom-drawn.  Guessing: don't use the Load event to change properties, that's *gauche*.

Comment: I also tested with this code: `this.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details; this.OwnerDraw = true; this.Columns.Add("X"); this.Items.Add("1"); this.Items.Add("2");` But nothing changed.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand your logic.  You are under the impression I'm doing something in a `Load` event and I'm under the impression that I'm not.  In the code I have, I only have code for the constructor not any `Load` event.  The `View` property is already set by the base class.  I'm really confused as to what direction you are going with your comment.

Comment: @RezaAghaei are you trying to set the View to Details or something?  Because the default should be LargeIcon.

Comment: Yes, I tried to set it to `Details` just for test. It doesn't matter what the view is.

Comment: I have added an example of what I see.  setting the view to `Tile` this is the effect it has for me.

Comment: It doesn't matter what `View` you use, it performs the default painting regardless of what you have in `OnDrawItem`. It's because it doesn't use  `OwnerDraw` property at design-time. The designer shadows it. This is the same behavior which you see for `Enabled` or `Visible` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer**

`ListViewDesigner` shadows `OwnerDraw` property like `Visible` or `Enabled` property of control. So it just works at run-time and changing it doesn't affect design-time.

**Side Note**

If you take a look at source code of `ListViewDesigner`, you will see this property:

```
private bool OwnerDraw
{
    get { return (bool) base.ShadowProperties["OwnerDraw"]; }
    set { base.ShadowProperties["OwnerDraw"] = value; }
}
```

And in `PreFilterProperties` you will see the designer replaced the original property with this one:

```
PropertyDescriptor oldPropertyDescriptor = (PropertyDescriptor) properties["OwnerDraw"];
if (oldPropertyDescriptor != null)
{
    properties["OwnerDraw"] = TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(typeof(ListViewDesigner), 
        oldPropertyDescriptor, new Attribute[0]);
}
```

So it doesn't matter what `View` you use, it performs the default painting regardless of what you have in `OnDrawItem`. It's because it doesn't use  `OwnerDraw` property at design-time. The designer shadows it. This is the same behavior which you see for `Enabled` or `Visible` property.

**Workaround to enable owner-draw at run-time**

As a workaround, you can register a different `Designer` for your derived control. This way the `OwnerDraw` property will work as a normal property:

```
[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
public class MyListView : ListView
```

**Warning:** Keep in mind, by registering a new designer for the control, you will lose the current `ListViewDesigner` features like its designer verbs or its smart tag (actions list) window or Column Sizing options. If you need those features, you can implement those features in a custom designer by looking into `ListViewDesigner` source code.

Comment: Is it possible to show these changes during design-time in a different way?

Comment: What changes? And how for example?

Comment: I added some codes from `ListViewDesigner` which I believe describes the reason.

Comment: "What changes?", well I would like to see my custom drawn listview in design time.  Is there no way to see them?  I remember in the past if I did something with the PAINT event or maybe it was subclass the WM_PAINT message to custom draw a control.  It showed all the changes I made in design time.  For example I could change a color as a prop and it would reflect in the form at design time.

Comment: Probably there is some workarounds for the problem. I guess you can enable owner-drawing using reflection or by sending messages, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Just did some testing and yea that was what I was looking for...  Last time I did subclassing and caught the `WM_PAINT` event.  If you don't pass on `base.WndProc(ref m);` nothing will be shown in the design view.  I think that's what I did last time on my custom control and was able to see the effects at design time.  The only problem here is that there is a LOT more involved with the paint message on a listview then a checkbox.  :)

Comment: You know your requirement better, but as an alternative, maybe creating a composite control (UserControl) help you to solve the problem simpler. - Or forget about design-time ;)

Comment: A workaround may be decorating your derived control with a new designer. This way the designer will not shadow `OwnerDraw` property and probably the owner drawing would work in design mode too. I didn't test it but I *guess* it's practical, but I don't know why Microsoft guys has shadowed the property and what would side effects of bringing it out of shadow.

Comment: So for example, I should NOT inherit the ListView class but do something like create my own property for View and have an underlying control created?  I would have to create events, properties, etc to match the listview class though...

Comment: No you should inherit `ListView`. Take a look at the other question which I answered recently. You derive from `ListView` and everything is like normal cases. Just decorate the derived class with a different designer class for example `[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]`.

Comment: I tested it and it works. I'll add it as a note in answer.

Comment: It seems we have some jealous users around who downvote question and answer without any reason/comment, just to fade the answer!